Is it possible to go up one line when pressing backspace, instead of deleting the indent, like in jetbrains?
In jetbrains, say you are at 1st level of indentation (1 tab). When pressing backspace, instead of deleting the indentation to the left, it goes up one line and automatically places an indentation on the correct level.
In vscode, it just removes one level of indentation, which is extremely frustrating.
